# Принадлежность точки четырехугольнику

Tags: алгоритм, c++

Помогите, пожалуйста, с данным алгоритмом. Нужно чтобы работал не только с выпуклыми. Если можно пример кода или псевдокод.

Comment: Проверять принадлежность 2-м треугольникам?)

Comment: А ведь правда.. :) Буду пробовать...

Comment: Я все-таки советую пользовать вариант из ответа) В оем еще для определения угла всякие косинусы для каждых 3 точек искать.

Comment: Как раз вариант с треугольниками проще в реализации. Проверка на попадание точки в треугольник это подсчёт 2 векторных произведений и сравнение их Z координат по знаку (т.к. треугольники лежат в плоскости):

http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/pointinpoly/default.html

Comment: Есть кое-что посвежее: [то же для многоугольника](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/464787/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/464796#464796)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проводим луч из проверяемой точки в любую бесконечно удаленную.

Для каждого ребра проверяем, пересекает ли данное ребро этот луч.

Если количество ребер которое луч пересекает четное, то точка вне многоугольника.

Если нечетное, то внутри.

Единственное, если данный луч проходит через пересечение соседних ребер, то определить нельзя или как то с бубном попытаться это сделать... Наверняка выход из этой ситуации есть.

PS [[@Sh4dow](/users/465/sh4dow)](/users/465/sh4dow) ваше предложение будет работать, только для выпуклого многоугольника. Если я неправильно понял, то пожалуйста объясните :)

UPD: вот реализация [hardfire.far.ru](http://hardfire.far.ru/index.php?id=point_in_polygon.htm)

Comment: Вводим точки по часовой стрелке. У невыпуклого 4-хугольника один угол из четырех будет отрицательным или больше 180 (смотря как считать). Если такой есть - берем эту точку за первую, если нет - любую. Строим 2 треугольника: (1, 2, 3) и (1, 3, 4). Если точка принадлежит любому из них - принадлежит и 4-хугольнику.

Хотя ваш вариант, скорее всего, полегче в плане расхода памяти и нагрузки.

Comment: Примерно так:

    .4
    
          .1 (угол > 180)
    
    .3    *наша точка       .2

Comment: @ilayer, для варианта @BogolyubskiyAlexey вам нужна одна формула - пересечение двух отрезков) например [вот](http://acmp.ru/article.asp?id_text=170) на дельфях. любая точка - да возьмите `{ 10000, 10000 }`. Посчитайте кол-во пересечений сторон многоугольника и отрезка (искомая точка, любая точка). Четность определить вроде не должно быть трудно))

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, про луч смутило сначала немного, в голове не сходилось))

Comment: Кстати та реализация нифига не работает правильно... Если допустим у меня четыре полигона и у каждого одна из точек имеет одинаковые координаты, то при проверке пригадлежности этой точки к каждому полигону выводит, что она только одному полигону принадлежит)) Засада короче.. Вот пример - http://i074.radikal.ru/1112/b2/2118c7ac645e.png

Comment: почему не правильно? судя по вашему рисунку как раз все правильно )) Если говорить о разделенном таким образом четырехугольнике, считая толщину линий-разделителей 0, имеем, что каждая точка родительского прямоугольника может принадлежать одному и только одному дочернему... это как отрезок вида [0; 5) - точка '0' включена в отрезок, а 5 - нет... то же самое - для проверки на пересечение с ребрами - обходите таким образом, чтобы начальная точка ребра "включалась" в ребро, а конечная - нет, тогда и ошибок быть не должно...

Comment: так же, по поводу реализации, можно брать не некую абстрактную точку пространства, а самую удаленную от заданной точки вершину многоугольника. На расчете расстояний от точки до каждой вершины - проигрываем, зато выигрываем считая, что "луч" пересекает одно из двух сходящихся в выбранной вершине ребер и не пересекает другое... Если возникают проблемы с невыпуклыми многоугольниками, можно считать, что если ребра, через точку пересечения (вершину) которых проведен луч, имеют начало с разных сторон от луча, то луч пересекает только одно из них, если по одну сторону - то оба... Вроде все случаи...