# Точка внутри многоугольника

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм

Допустим есть многоугольник из N (и это главное) вершин. И есть точка в произвольном месте. Необходимо определить принадлежит она ему или нет. Точки представлены в виде структуры:

```
struct point{ unsigned int x; unsigned int y;};
```

Все решения и алгоритмы которые я находил были написаны для четырехугольников и для треугольников. Главное уточнение многоугольник может быть выпуклый и не выпуклый.

Я остановился на идеи подсчитать сколько сторон луч выпущенный из точки пройдет. если четное число - не в многоугольнике. если не четное - в многоугольнике. То есть нам надо указывать вершины по часовой стрелке. Сделать структуру сторон. Но как проверять? Как расчитать эти стороны и сделать пересечение?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Плохо ищете.

```
bool result = false;
int j = size - 1;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if ( (p[i].Y < point.Y && p[j].Y >= point.Y || p[j].Y < point.Y && p[i].Y >= point.Y) &&
         (p[i].X + (point.Y - p[i].Y) / (p[j].Y - p[i].Y) * (p[j].X - p[i].X) < point.X) )
        result = !result;
    j = i;
}
```

- p - список точек
- size - количество точек
- result - входит ли точка в многоугольник

Первая строка условия проверяет попадание `point.Y` между значениями `p[i].Y` и `p[j].Y`, контролирует направление прохода вершины и обеспечивает ненулевой знаменатель основной формулы.

Вторая строка проверяет нахождение стороны `p[i]p[j]` слева от точки `point`.

Третья строка формирует отрицательный ответ при чётном количестве сторон слева и положительный — при нечётном.

Comment: А есть какой либо еще способ?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Вроде, всегда этот используют. Можно оптимизировать, заранее вычислив описывающую фигуру (прямоугольник), тогда большинство проверок будет быстрыми.

Comment: данный способ основывается не на "выпуске луча" на сколько я понимаю

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Горизонтальный луч же, если мне не изменяет зрение.

Comment: https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83

Answer (score 5):

Пусть луч направлен горизонтально вправо.

Для каждой пары смежных точек:

1. Сначала проверяете, лежит ли пара точек (краев отрезка) по одну сторону луча. Если по одну сторону - то луч не пересекает сторону.
2. Если по разные стороны - нужно найти точку пересечения луча и прямой, проходящей через две данные точки. Это аналитическая геометрия, по сути, решение приводить не буду. Если точка пересечения правее точки, откуда исходит луч - значит пересечение есть.

Нужно учитывать специальный случай, когда луч проходит через вершину многоугольника:

1. Если вторые точки обоих отрезков, которым принадлежит данная вершина находятся по одну сторону от луча, то считать это двумя пересечениями (или отсутствием пресечения - четность будет та же)
2. Если вторые точки по разные стороны луча - считать одним пересечением.

Можно избежать необходимости проверки прохождения через точки, если точки многоугольника находятся в узлах сетки (например если координаты всегда целые, или заданы с фиксированной точностью): достаточно сместить точку, откуда исходит луч, вверх или вниз на небольшую величину (например на машинный эпсилон) тогда луч практически гарантированно не пройдет ни через одну из точек многоугольника.

Comment: Ещё к специальному случаю относится сторона целиком лежащая на луче