# Определение факта пересечения 3D треугольников

Tags: алгоритм, математика, геометрия

Есть 2 треугольника заданные тремя пространственными координатами (x,y,z)
Допустим у нас есть подозрение по их пересечению треугольников (образующие кубы пересекаются).

Вопрос: как определить факт пересечения этих треугольников.
Поясню. Мне не нужно знать в каком отрезке они пересекаются, и даже не нужно знать одну из точек пересечения. Меня интересует "быстрый" алгоритм поиска факта пересечения, т.е. `true` или `false`.

<del>З.Ы.: Искал в интернете, есть алгоритмы нахождения пересечения, а факта нет. И существуют ли вообще упращенные алгоритмы?</del>

З.Ы.: Кое что нашёл. Есть сайт [RealTimeRendering](http://www.realtimerendering.com/intersections.html), Там есть метод [Fast Triangle-Triangle Intersection test by Tomas Möller](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs277/resources/papers/Moller1997b.pdf). Пока изучаю его. Подозреваю, что есть более быстрые алгоритмы.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

После поисков по просторам итернетов я нашел оптимальный [способ описанный Томасом Моллером](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs277/resources/papers/Moller1997b.pdf). Написал код под C# для данного алгоритма.

```
public bool PointInTriangle2D(float[][] t, float[] p)
{
  bool inside = false;
  int j = 2; // = 3 - 1
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    if ((t[i][1] < p[1] && t[j][1] >= p[1] || t[j][1] < p[1] && t[i][1] >= p[1]) &&
        (t[i][0] + (p[1] - t[i][1]) / (t[j][1] - t[i][1]) * (t[j][0] - t[i][0]) < p[0]))
      inside = !inside;
    j = i;
  }
  return inside;
}

public bool Moller1997b(Vertex[] V0, Vertex[] V1)
{
  return Moller1997b(new Vertex[2][] { V0, V1 });
}

public bool Moller1997b(Vertex[][] V)
{
  float[][] dv = new float[2][];
  int[][] sign = new int[2][];
  float[][] pv = new float[2][];
  float[][] t = new float[2][];
  float[][] triange2D = new float[3][];
  float[] point2D = new float[2];
  for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
    triange2D[j] = new float[2];
  for (int j = 0; j < 2; ++j)
  {
    dv[j] = new float[3];
    sign[j] = new int[3];
    pv[j] = new float[3];
    t[j] = new float[2];
  }

  //Находим вектор-нормаль ко второму треугольнику 
  Vertex N1 = (V[1][1] - V[1][0]).VectorProduct(V[1][2] - V[1][0]);
  //и коэфициент плоскости второго треугольника
  float d1 = -N1.ScalarProduct(V[1][0]);
  //Уровнение плоскости второго треугольника будет выглядеть 
  //π2 : N2*X+d2=0, где X-любая точка плоскости (одна из точек v2)
  //Но нам это в данной задаче не важно
  //Проверяем с какой стороны плоскости лежат точки первого треугольника
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
  {
    dv[0][i] = N1.ScalarProduct(V[0][i]) + d1;
    sign[0][i] = Math.Abs(dv[0][i]) > epsilant ? Math.Sign(dv[0][i]) : 0;
  }
  //Треугольник 0 не пересекается с плоскостью другого треугольника
  if (sign[0][0].Equals(sign[0][1]) && sign[0][1].Equals(sign[0][2]) && !sign[0][0].Equals(0))
    return false;
  //Треугольники в одной плоскости
  //Как показала практика такие случаи оооочень большая редкость
  if (sign[0][0].Equals(sign[0][1]) && sign[0][1].Equals(sign[0][2]) && sign[0][0].Equals(0))
  {
    //Теперь выберем на какую плоскость (xy, yz, xz) спроецируем треугольники
    float aNX = Math.Abs(N1.X);
    float aNY = Math.Abs(N1.Y);
    float aNZ = Math.Abs(N1.Z);
    float maxN = Math.Max(aNX, Math.Max(aNY, aNZ));
    //Какую компоненту будем игнорить
    int ignoreIndex = (aNX.Equals(maxN)) ? 0 : (aNY.Equals(maxN)) ? 1 : 2;
    //Какие компоненты будем использовать для 2D координат
    int iX = ignoreIndex == 0 ? 2 : 0;
    int iY = ignoreIndex == 1 ? 2 : 1;
    //Проверка принадлежности хотябы одной точки треугольника 0 треугольнику 1
    //http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/464787/Точка-внутри-многоугольника
    for (int p = 0; p < 3; ++p)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
      {
        triange2D[i][0] = V[1][i][iX];
        triange2D[i][1] = V[1][i][iY];
      }
      point2D[0] = V[0][p][iX];
      point2D[1] = V[0][p][iY];
      if (PointInTriangle2D(triange2D, point2D))
        return true;
    }
    //или центр масс второго треугольника 1 попадает в треугольник 0. Заодно включает 
    //вопрос совподения (или очень близкого к совпадению) трех точек одного треугольника и трех точек другого треугольника
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
      triange2D[i][0] = V[0][i][iX];
      triange2D[i][1] = V[0][i][iY];
    }
    point2D[0] = (V[1][0][iX] + V[1][1][iX] + V[1][2][iX]) / 3f;
    point2D[1] = (V[1][0][iY] + V[1][1][iY] + V[1][2][iY]) / 3f;
    if (PointInTriangle2D(triange2D, point2D))
      return true;
    return false;
  }
  Vertex N0 = (V[0][1] - V[0][0]).VectorProduct(V[0][2] - V[0][0]);
  float d0 = -N0.ScalarProduct(V[0][0]);
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
  {
    dv[1][i] = N0.ScalarProduct(V[1][i]) + d0;
    sign[1][i] = Math.Abs(dv[1][i]) > epsilant ? Math.Sign(dv[1][i]) : 0;
  }
  //Треугольник 1 не пересекается с плоскостью другого треугольника
  if (sign[1][0].Equals(sign[1][1]) && sign[1][1].Equals(sign[1][2]) && !sign[1][0].Equals(0))
    return false;
  //Треугольники на разных плоскостях
  Vertex D = N0.VectorProduct(N1);
  float aDX = Math.Abs(D.X);
  float aDY = Math.Abs(D.Y);
  float aDZ = Math.Abs(D.Z);
  float maxD = Math.Max(aDX, Math.Max(aDY, aDZ));
  int Tindex = (aDX.Equals(maxD)) ? 0 : (aDY.Equals(maxD)) ? 1 : 2;
  for (int j = 0; j < 2; ++j)
  {
    //l и r это индексы точек находящихся по одну из сторон плоскости j
    int c = 1, l = 0, r = 2;
    if (sign[j][0].Equals(sign[j][1])) { c = 2; r = 0; l = 1; }
    else if (sign[j][1].Equals(sign[j][2])) { c = 0; r = 2; l = 1; } //Иначе оставляем без изменений
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
      pv[j][i] = pv[j][i] = V[j][i][Tindex];//D.ScalarProduct(V[j][i]); //pv[j][i] = V[j][i][Tindex];
    t[j][0] = pv[j][l] + (pv[j][c] - pv[j][l]) * dv[j][l] / (dv[j][l] - dv[j][c]);
    t[j][1] = pv[j][r] + (pv[j][c] - pv[j][r]) * dv[j][r] / (dv[j][r] - dv[j][c]);
    if (t[j][0] > t[j][1])
    {
      float _t = t[j][0];
      t[j][0] = t[j][1];
      t[j][1] = _t;
    }
  }
  return (t[0][0] < t[1][1]) && (t[0][1] > t[1][0]);
}
```

где `ScalarProduct` и `VectorProduct` это векторные и скалярные произведения соответственно

```
public float ScalarProduct(Vertex rhs)
{
  return X * rhs.X + Y * rhs.Y + Z * rhs.Z;
}

public Vertex VectorProduct(Vertex rhs)
{
  return new Vertex((Y * rhs.Z) - (Z * rhs.Y), (Z * rhs.X) - (X * rhs.Z),
      (X * rhs.Y) - (Y * rhs.X));
}
```

Comment: Если это не является ответом, то зачем это размещать как ответ? Тем более, что это ответ-ссылка, что так же не приветствуется правилами сайта.

Comment: Вы вообще читаете что написано? "Пока ответом считать не буду, т.к. подозреваю есть более быстрые способы." слово "Пока" вам ничего не говорит? И также "Пока изучаю его. Код выложу позже." тоже ни о чем не говорит? Мой предответ, возможно, будет помощью для тех, кто ищет решение аналогичной задачи.

Comment: Уважаемый Дмитрий, SO это база прикладных вопросов и решений. В текущем виде, такой анонс ответа не является решением. Возможно стоит включить эту ссылку в вопрос.

Answer (score -1):

Записываем точки в виде `(1, ax, ay, az)`

Считаем плоскость как вектор-определитель (D, A, B, C)

```
i  j  k  e
1 ax ay az
1 bx by bz
1 cx cy cz
```

Аналогично пересекаем две получившиеся плоскости.

Comment: А точно столбец из единиц не справа?

Comment: @VladD, однородные координаты. Вроде слева, как первая координата. А вообще, я сейчас подумал, что пересечение плоскостей не будет означать пересечение треугольников.

Comment: Ну это да, не означает. Но всё же, непонятно, почему первая координата выделена. Давайте проверим на точках (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1), которые должны давать плоскость x + y + z = 1.

Answer (score -1):

Два выпуклых объекта не пересекаются тогда и только тогда, когда существует плоскость (для двумерного случая - прямая), такая, что проекции геометрий на эту плоскость (прямую) не пересекаются.
http://home.arcor.de/philippe.guigue/triangle_triangle_intersection.htm

Comment: Окей. И как использовать этот факт? По ссылке написано что-то по теме, но если вы предоставите выжимку или лучше алгоритм, ваш ответ будет гораздо ценнее.

Comment: есть алгоритм на с++(он в конце статьи)

Comment: http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/MethodOfSeparatingAxes.pdf