# Находится ли точка внутри 2D многоугольника

Tags: c#, математика, геометрия

Как узнать находится ли точка внутри 2D многоугольника? (!!!углов может быть сколько угодно). Координатная плоскость и условные многоугольники прикрепил ниже. Вопрос актуален как для выпуклых многоугольников, так и для невыпуклых.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Задача о принадлежности точки многоугольнику](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83) ?

Comment: [алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/464787/178576)